# Comparing sequential columns inside a For Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, correlation

I'm trying to create a for loop to compare multiple variables at once. My df is like this:

```
VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2, VARIABLE3, VARIABLE4 .... (so on)
```

I need to compare the sequential varibales, i.e:

VARIBALE1, VARIBLE2
VARIABLE 3, VARIABLE4,
so on... (I have ten comparisions in total)

My ideia was to create a for loop in with VAR1 would be i + 1 and VAR2 would be i + 2, but it's not working the way I thought It would...

```
 Corrn <- 10

  for (ii in 1:Corrn) {
  
  CorrVar1 <- dfCorr1[ii + 1]
  CorrnVar1 <- names(CorrVar1)
  
  print(CorrnVar1)

   for (ii in 1:Corrn) {
    
    CorrVar2 <- dfCorr1[ii+2]
    CorrnVar2 <- names(CorrVar2)
    
    print(CorrnVar2)
    
    }
}
```

I'm not getting VARIABLE 1 (var1) and VARIABLE 2 (as var2) in the SAME loop (which is what I need). Rather, loops are going on and on. I get this:

```
i.e, when i = 1, var 1 = VARIABLE1, var 2 = VARIABLE2, 
     when i = 2, var 1 = VARIABLE 2, var 2 = VARIABLE 3
```

but what I need is this:

```
i.e, when i = 1, var 1 = VARIABLE1, var 2 = VARIABLE2, 

     when i = 2, var 1 = VARIABLE 3, var 2 = VARIABLE 4
```

and so on... any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you want `for(i in seq(1, 10, by = 2))` or something like that---not sure how many columns you have.

Comment: Also I can't tell from your explanation if you want a nested loop or not. Nesting will give you pairs like {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, ... {3, 4}, {3, 5}, etc. If you want {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} only, you only need one loop.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend putting some `print` statements in your loop to help you know what's going on. If `i` is 1, then *"`VAR1` would be `i + 1`"* doesn't make sense--VAR1 is just i. If you need more help, please make s small reproducible example: share code to create, say, 6 sample columns of data, and be very clear about your desired result for those 6 columns.

Comment: @GregorThomas , yes, indeed my variables of interest start at column 4, so my actual code was i + 3 and i +4, I thought of writing i + 1 and i +2 so that it would be easier to understand, you've got a good point, I'm sorry! Yes, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9} that's exaclty what I need!

Comment: @GregorThomas, I adapted your solution to seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 2) and it worked just fine! thank you!!